# Where to begin studying synthesis of classical instruments?

Tags: synthesis

I would be very interested in learning how to realistically synthesize classical instruments (piano and strings in particular).
Could you point me to a *command line* software (or something that I can control using *text*), and a beginner text to understand it?

(the requisite for a text controllable software comes from the fact that I'd like to embed this software in another programming language, to automate certain operations.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Textual languages are less popular these days as graphical audio programming environments (such as Max or Pd) are more approachable.  Nonetheless a couple that you may like to look at are Csound ([The Csound Book: Perspectives in Software Synthesis, Sound Design, Signal Processing and Programming, Richard Boulanger](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Csound-Book-Perspectives-Programming/dp/0262522616/)), which is a C based language so if you have any programming experience you can jump straight in. The other is SuperCollider which is an interpreted language and fairly easy to pick up the basic syntax ([The SuperCollider Book, Scott Wilson, David Cottle, Nick Collins](http://www.amazon.co.uk/SuperCollider-Book-Scott-Wilson/dp/0262232693/)).

Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for Max or Pure Data (free, same developer as Max). Both are object based programming tools based on C. So you should be able to convert that into Code.

edit: also you just need to learn how to use the IAC driver on macs to understand how to deliver midi/automation data from program to program. -> Prog midi control in Pure data and then feed it via the IAC driver (audio midi setup in mac-utilities) to any other software